# Does the BizTalk 2013 R2 SharePoint adapter support HTTPS?

Tags: https, sharepoint-2013, biztalk, csom, biztalk-2013

I'm looking into a potential integration solution that would use BizTalk 2013 R2 to interact with a SharePoint Online using the Client Side Object Model. However, I want to keep security in mind and so I'm trying to verify that the WSS adapter supports HTTPS. I can't find anywhere in the documentation that states this explicitly, and it will take some effort before I'm capable of testing it out.

Is it sufficient to simply use an https URL with port 443 to configure the WSS adapter to use HTTPS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[What Is the Windows SharePoint Services Adapter?](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa558796.aspx)

> Permissions to Windows SharePoint Services files, lists, and document libraries are restricted using Windows SharePoint Services security. The messages are sent from Windows SharePoint Services directly into BizTalk Server. The communication between the adapter runtime and the Web service is done over HTTP or **HTTPS**.
>
> The adapter assumes that the BTSharePointAdapterWS Web service is using the same HTTP scheme (HTTP or **HTTPS**) as the Windows SharePoint Services site. This means that the adapter will use **HTTPS** to communicate with the BTSSharePointAdapterWS Web service when the Windows SharePoint Services Site is created on a secure IIS Web site, or it will use HTTP to communicate with the BTSharePointAdapterWS Web service when the Windows SharePoint Services site is created on an IIS Web site without a server certificate.

(Bolding added for emphasis).

Configure the SharePoint Site URL to have https:// and you should not have to specify the port.

Comment: This link is for the old SSOM, which is now deprecated, while the documentation for the CSOM makes no mention of HTTPS. Sorry if this is obvious--is there some detail why the underlying implementation for the two should be the same?

Comment: @bwerks How about this https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2859398/fix-biztalk-server-2013-cannot-receive-messages-from-the-view-in-the-document-library-or-from-a-sharepoint-online-library  It mentions a URI with port 443

Comment: It's a bit indirect, but it's promising enough to go on. Thanks!